# predict len of an sprintf( )'ed line?

Tags: c, printf, string-length

Is there a function around somewhere that I can use to predict the space that sprintf( ) will need? IOW, can I call a function size_t predict_space( "%s\n", some_string ) that will return the length of the C-string that will result from sprintf( "%s\n", some_string )?

Comment: Why not just use `strlen` on `some_string` and use that to calculate how much space is needed?

Comment: @MAK Presumably the OP wants a general solution that will work with different format specifiers and multiple parameters.

Comment: As per the answers, `snprintf` is probably the way to go. In systems without that function, we've used `FILE *fh = fopen ("/dev/null", "w")` and then `x = fprintf (fh, fmtstr, blah, blah, blah);` to get the length.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In **C99** `snprintf` *(note: Windows and SUSv2, do not provide an implementation of snprintf (or _snprintf) conforming to the Standard)*:

```
       7.19.6.5  The snprintf function

       Synopsis

       [#1]

               #include <stdio.h>
               int snprintf(char * restrict s, size_t n,
                       const char * restrict format, ...);

       Description

       [#2]  The snprintf function is equivalent to fprintf, except
       that the output is  written  into  an  array  (specified  by
       argument  s) rather than to a stream.  If n is zero, nothing
       is written, and s may be a null pointer.  Otherwise,  output
       characters  beyond the n-1st are discarded rather than being
       written to the array, and a null character is written at the
       end  of  the characters actually written into the array.  If
       copying  takes  place  between  objects  that  overlap,  the
       behavior is undefined.

       Returns

       [#3]  The snprintf function returns the number of characters
       that would have been written had n been sufficiently  large,
       not  counting  the terminating null character, or a negative
       value if  an  encoding  error  occurred.   Thus,  the  null-
       terminated output has been completely written if and only if
       the returned value is nonnegative and less than n.
```

For example:

```
len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s\n", some_string);
if (len > 0) {
    newstring = malloc(len + 1);
    if (newstring) {
        snprintf(newstring, len + 1, "%s\n", some_string);
    }
}
```

Comment: Might not be portable:Concerning the return value of snprintf, the SUSv2 and the  C99  stan-
       dard  contradict  each other: when snprintf is called with size=0 then
       SUSv2 stipulates an unspecified return value less than  1,  while  C99
       allows  str  to  be  NULL in this case, and gives the return value (as
       always) as the number of characters that would have  been  written  in
       case the output string has been large enough.

Comment: @Benoit, you could probably use something like `char x; int len = snprintf (&x, 1, fmtstr, blah, blah, blah);` in that case.

Answer (score 6):

Use can use snprintf() with a size of of 0 to find out exactly how many bytes will be required. The price is that the string is in effect formatted twice.

Comment: Take care. Extract of man page:The snprintf() function returns  the  number  of  characters
     formatted, that is, the number of characters that would have
     been written to the buffer if it were large enough.  If  the
     value  of  n  is  0  on a call to snprintf(), an unspecified
     value less than 1 is returned.

Comment: @Benoit: that is not the behaviour the Standard describes.

Comment: Concerning the return value of snprintf, the SUSv2 and the  C99  stan-
       dard  contradict  each other: when snprintf is called with size=0 then
       SUSv2 stipulates an unspecified return value less than  1,  while  C99
       allows  str  to  be  NULL in this case, and gives the return value (as
       always) as the number of characters that would have  been  written  in
       case the output string has been large enough.

Comment: SUSv4 however, stipulates the desired behavior.  However, often one passes n == 1 to snprintf which (sometimes) works when passing n == 0 does not.

Comment: SUSv3 is aligned with C99 and therefore also stipulates the desired behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `snprintf` for that, as in

```
sz = snprintf (NULL, 0, fmt, arg0, arg1, ...);
```

But see Autoconf's [portability notes](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/autoconf/Function-Portability.html) on `snprintf`.

Comment: Warning:Concerning the return value of snprintf, the SUSv2 and the  C99  stan-
       dard  contradict  each other: when snprintf is called with size=0 then
       SUSv2 stipulates an unspecified return value less than  1,  while  C99
       allows  str  to  be  NULL in this case, and gives the return value (as
       always) as the number of characters that would have  been  written  in
       case the output string has been large enough.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, you can compute it by adding length of the string you are concatenating and taking max length for numeric values based on the format you used.